# My react-hook-form is sending an empty array to axios request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I have a container with mui `<Chips>`. Inside the Chips are labels. The goal is to use these chips as a selector, via `onClick`, which append the label values to a list which then gets sent to an Axios request. All doing so without any textfield, these `<Chips>` are static.

For every Chip selected, I can see it's label console logged in an array (which is expected), this is how I know I've set up most everything correctly for the most part.

However, I'm not linking the form correctly to my onSubmit axios function because I'm sending empty arrays to my database:

Here is my code:
This is my onSubmit function

```
    const onSubmit = (data, e) =>
      {  
        console.log(data);
    
        axiosInstance
          .patch(URL, {
            stock_list: data.stock_list,
          })
          .then((res) =>
          {
            console.log(res);
            console.log(res.data);
          });
    };
```

Here is my toggle function and form.

```
    //This toggle function handles my chips when a user selects them
    const handleToggle = (value) => () => {
        const currentIndex = checked.indexOf(value);
        const newChecked = [...checked];
     
        if (currentIndex === -1) {
            newChecked.push(value);
        } else {
            newChecked.splice(currentIndex, 1);
        }
     
        setChecked(newChecked);
        };
  
        console.log(checked);

          
return (
 <>
  <form noValidate  onSubmit = { handleSubmit(onSubmit) }>
                <Controller
                    render={({ onChange ,...props }) => (
                        <Paper component="ul" className={classes.root}>
                            {stocklist.map((value, index) =>
                            {
                                return (
                                    <li key={index}>
                                    <Chip
                                    variant="outlined"
                                    label={value}
                                    key={index}
                                    color={checked.includes(value) ? 'secondary' : 'primary'}
                                    onClick={handleToggle(value)}
                                    className={classes.chip}
                                    ref={register}
                                    />
                                  </li> 
                                );
                            })}
                        </Paper>
                    )}
                    name="stock_list"
                    control={control}
                    defaultValue={[]}
                    onChange={([, data]) => data}
                    />
                <Fab
                    color="primary"
                    aria-label="delete"
                    type="submit"
                    >
                    <DeleteIcon />
                </Fab>
            </form>
</>
```

*Visual aids:*
Here I select 3 chips

[image]

stock_list is the console logged empty array that's being sent over to my database in a successful request. As you see, I've also console logged the three chips that were toggled successfully?

[image]

How can I properly send the list of toggled values to my Axios request? I'm using `react-hook-form` to help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `onChannge` as received in the `render` props to the `onClick` prop of your chip.
The `onChange` passed to the `Controller` won't have any effect.
I might be able to help you out better if you made a sandbox for this.